# woocommerce: how to access an order purchase in database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to access users purchase information from my wordpress admin plugin so that I can summarise orders e.g:

- Product name
- Custom data (in my case text associated with the
  product)
- When it was bought
- How much they paid

It's mostly the information you can find on the "Account" > "Orders" page when the user is logged in.

I've looked through the woocommerce tables but can't find this information.

Can you suggest which tables I can query to pull together the information I'm looking for above?

Answer (score 0):

The orders are stored at the **wp_posts** table with a **'shop_order'** custom post type.
You can simply use the woocommerce function like this.

```
$woo_orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );

/* Loop each WC_Order object */
foreach( $woo_orders $order ){

  /* Get the ID */
  echo $order->get_id();

  /* Get the status */
  echo $order->get_status(); // The status
}
```

Or use the normal wordpress loop:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
   'posts_per_page'    => -1,
   'post_status'       =>  'wc-ywraq-new' //will get the new order
) );

// Your post loop
if ( $loop->have_posts() ): 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    // The ID
    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;

    // The object from WC_Order find the reference in woocommerce docs
    $order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);

  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata(); // always

endif;
```

Here's the reference from github: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But does that actually tell you whether the purchase was successful?